# Whitelisting List of Multipart files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, whitelist

I am wondering if there was a tool that is available in the Spring package that could allow me to Whitelist multiple types for a single API, (i.e. no content type = application/pdf), I am largely targeting only images, documents and sounds, may I know what would be the best practice in implementing such checks?

My API aims to take in files via a list of multipart files, and the attach a unique UUID for the request before storing it in a local file server.

My current code allows Multiple multipart files to be attached, hopefully there is an established way to check such files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the content type from the `MultipartFile` and use that:

```
private void checkIfImageType(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
  String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
  if( !contentType.equals("image/jpg")
       && !contentType....) { // Add more checks as needed
    throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported content: " + contentType);
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the content type has extra stuff. Use can use this helper method to strip it before you check the content type:

```
    private static String stripExtrasFromContentTypeIfNeeded(String contentType) {
        int index = contentType.indexOf(';');
        if (index != -1) {
            contentType = contentType.substring(0, index);
        }
        return contentType;
    }
```